# How to Create an array of pointers to structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I have

```
struct Item {int id; string name; float sellprice; int qstock;};
struct Sale {int id; int quantity; double tcost;};
```

I want to create an array, with 100 indexes, such that when i dereference the array position, 
i'll be at the struct position. Also the structs must be assigned memory using malloc.

e.g.

```
*(items[0]).id=10; //will store id=10 in first index struct.
```

however i am unsure how to declare the array of pointers.
do i need to make a pointer to the struct, and then an array of that pointers?

```
itemsPtr *Item;
itemsPtr items[100];
items[0]->id=10;
```

or will it be something like.

```
Item *items[100];
```

I tried a few of these variants and have had problems. Also when i have to pass this array of pointers to a function do i just pass the array name as that is a pointer or what?

Comment: also how would i malloc a struct before use, the use of new is forbidden

Comment: You've marked this as C++.  Do not use malloc / free.  Use new / delete.

Comment: Do you really code in C++? Maybe C is more appropriate?

Comment: It's a school thing, yes ik about new and delete. It's a fundamentals course building on C. I didn't make the course.

Comment: The above comments clearly shows why its hard to find how to do something not commonly found, because people rather spend time judging instead of being helpful toward the specified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using C, you might do something like:

```
Item* items[100]; //an array of Item*
```

To allocate a new `Item`, and store a pointer to this `Item` in the array, you might do something like:

```
items[i] = malloc(sizeof(Item));
```

To access an element you can use the de-reference (`*`) or arrow (`->`) operators. The latter is probably prefered if you just want to access a member of the struct:

```
items[i]->id
*(items[i]).id
```

To pass the array to a function you can just pass the array `items` just like you would a normal array.

Before the array passes out of scope, make sure to clean up the allocated `Item`s. So, for each value that you initialized in the array:

```
free(items[i])
```

Of course, if you are using C++, you would want to avoid using `malloc`/`free` and instead use the `new` and `delete` operators, as is standard (you cannot mix them).

Comment: Thanks You Very Much! This Cleared it up a lot for me

Comment: Are you sure in C it's not `struct Item* items[100]`?